# Estimating Lull Time for Ocean Swells

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

I am looking for a method of computing lulls between sets of ocean waves from data I would have available from a local buoy. By lull, I mean the time between sets of waves, where the average wave height is small compared to the waves in a set. Based off experience, the lulls seem varied in length, so having some kind of mean and variance estimates would be what I'd want.

Are there any known methods of estimating the lull period for ocean swells?

I have tried computing estimates by looking at the energy density function, but this doesn't appear to yield any useful answer. I was trying to estimate the local rms height of the waves as a function of time from the energy function (something readily available from buoys) and then compute the dominate frequency in this rms function. Unfortunately, I was unable to get a function that was time cyclic in nature.

Comment: Can you define "lull period"?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be fairly easy. We can get it from the [Group Velocity Derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_velocity#Derivation).

Taking the second term in,

$$
\omega (k)\approx \omega _{0}+(k-k_{0})\omega'_0
$$

And computing its expectation using deep water approximation,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\left[(k-k_{0})\omega '_{0}\right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\frac{\omega^2}{g} - \frac{\omega_0^2}{g} \right)\frac{g}{2\ \omega_0}\right] \\
  &= \frac{Var[\omega]}{2\ \mathbb{E}[\omega]}
\end{align}

Most data coming off buoys is not in radial Hertz, but just Hertz. So we need to stick in the factor of $ 2\pi $.

Computing the period is then,
\begin{align}
T &= 2\pi \frac{2\ \mathbb{E}[\omega]}{Var[\omega]} \\
  &= \frac{2\ \mathbb{E}[f]}{Var[f]}
\end{align}

Uncertainty can be computed via the standard propagation technique,
\begin{align}
\Delta T &= \sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial \omega_{lull}}\right)^2 Var[\omega_{lull}]} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\mathbb{E}[f_{lull}]^2} \sqrt{Var[f_{lull}]}
\end{align}

**Practical Hint**

In computing the mean and variance, noise might obscure the swell signal. This can be filtered out with a scaling method.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
>>> y = 2.0*np.exp(-(x-3.0)**2/(2*1.5**2)) + 1.0*np.exp(-(x-5.0)**)/(2.0*2.3**2))
>>> scale = 1.0
>>> avg = np.average(x, weights=y**scale)
>>> std = (np.average((x - avg)**2, weights=y**scale)*scale)**0.5>>> print avg, std
3.82262283639 2.06430285503
>>> scale = 30.0
>>> avg = np.average(x, weights=y**scale)
>>> std = (np.average((x - avg)**2, weights=y**scale)*scale)**0.5
>>> print avg, std
3.29350912846 1.74737043027
```

Note that we are converging on the main mean and stdev of the distribution.